# JQuery AJax on CodeIgniter: JSON datatype returning null

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and it's my first time working with jquery ajax.

I have a modal form that passes information to a script on the view. The problem I have is that the ajax is giving null values...
I tried to alert the data on the script and it is displaying the proper values, but when it passes the data as a json to the controller, I think that's where it's failing. I don't know what to do. Do you have any idea?

snippet of the script on the view

```
 $(function () { //add new user from modal
    $('#adduser_modal').modal('show');
    $('#adduser_modal').find('.modal-title').text('Add New User');
    $('#addUser_form').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>Hgv_controller/addnewuser');
});
$('#saveuser_btn').click(function () {
    var url = $('#addUser_form').attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        jsonpcallback: success
    :
    function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            $('#adduser_modal').modal('hide');
            $('#addUser_form')[0].reset();
        }
    }
});
```

here's a snippet of code from the controller

```
public function addnewuser()
{
    $this->load->database();
    //load model for crud
    $this->load->model('Crud');
    $result = $this->Crud->adduser();

    $msg['success'] = false;
    $msg['type'] = 'add';
    if ($result) {
        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

and here's a snippet from the model

```
public function adduser()
{
    $field = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('hgv_username'),
        'f_name' => $this->input->post('hgv_firstname'),
        'l_name' => $this->input->post('hgv_lastname'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('hgv_password'),
        'user_type' => $this->input->post('hgv_type'),
    );
    $this->db->insert('hgv_user', $field);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to dump or print the post data you are getting in your model?? to verify

Comment: or try print_r($this->input->post()); exit; after you load your model in your controller to see if you are getting data in controller or not

Comment: 1. `ajax` is not a valid http request method (`type:'ajax'`), 2. `type` is an alias for `method`, 3. `async:false` makes the request synchron and blocks the script/UI, 4. the `$.ajax(...)` options object has a syntax error (the unnecessary `jsonpcallback` property)

Comment: I'm having errors if I put that on the controller.. How else can i check if i'm receiving the right data on the controller?

Comment: yes, @andreas . I already edited the syntax. I overlooked it as I was looking for some solutions to try. what should I put on the type? I'm sorry if I sound stupid right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `jsonpcallback` seems to be inappropriate. Give this a try

```
$('#saveuser_btn').click(function () {
    var url = $('#addUser_form').attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            $('#adduser_modal').modal('hide');
            $('#addUser_form')[0].reset();
        } else {
          alert('New User was not added.');
        }
    }
```

I also remove a couple of ajax options that you probably should not have used.
The rest of your code looks good but you could make your controller a tiny bit more efficient by using this.

```
public function addnewuser()
{
    $this->load->database();
    //load model for crud
    $this->load->model('Crud');
    $msg['success'] = $this->Crud->adduser();
    $msg['type'] = 'add';
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

Your model already returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` so put that return directly in the `$msg` array.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the same result; it's still entering the database as null.

Comment: How and where are you setting the value of the var `data`?